# Compare 2D maps

Tags: distributions, image-processing

I have a bunch of samples to compare. Each sample is composed of 30,000 cells (dots) for which I computed 2 dimensions (30,000 x 2 matrix). Each dot represent the expression of two parameters for a particular cell (I am dealing with flow cytometry data).

I am looking for a metric that would tell me how similar two samples are (if I plot them in 2D and the dots are co-localized (the joint expression of the two parameters is similar) I would like to have a high similarity, if on the other hand the dots are located on different regions of the 2D map I would like to have a low similarity).

Following suggestions I have tried to use the Jensen-Shannon divergence to compare 2D histograms but it does not seem to give me the expected result (sample whose cells are co-localized give me the same metric as samples whose cells are not co-localized maybe because the density of the co-localized cells is not the same in the more similar samples).

Is there any other metric I could try? Or should I use the Jensen-Shannon divergence on something else than the 2D histograms?

Thanks a lot in advance
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Although I can't answer the question, I would suggest that you might find some inspiration in the literature on change detection in remote sensing. Your problem looks very similar to that of finding the change between two satellite images taken at different times.

Comment: This question really isn't objectively answerable without some information about what the images represent and why you are comparing them.  Would you care to edit it to include such information?

Comment: I am not exactly dealing with images. I am comparing 2D plots of 30,000 cells in 2 dimensions.